# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Não sei o pq ocorre esse erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Segue código:

```
var app = angular.module('Teste');
app.controller('testeController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.formulario = {};
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        $scope.tipos = sema.tipoSimfiscal;
        $scope.municipios = sema.municipios;
        $scope.estados = sema.estados;
        $scope.categoriasProdutos = sema.categoriasProdutos;
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.municipioDestinos = [];
        $scope.dTableOptions = {
            aoColumns: [
                { "sTitle": "Tipo" },
                { "sTitle": "Nº GF" },
                { "sTitle": "Nº DVPF" },
                { "sTitle": "Remetente" },
                { "sTitle": "Destinatário" },
                { "sTitle": "Situação" },
                { "sTitle": "" }
            ]
        };

        $scope.municipioDestinos = function (form) {
            $http.post('views/transparencia/sistemas/service.aspx/Consultar', {
                estado: form.estado || ''
            }).then(function (success) {
                let data = JSON.parse(success.data.d);
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.municipioDestinos = data;
            }, function (error) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
            });
        };

        $scope.abrirModal = function (id) {
            let item = $scope.data.filter(function (it) { return it.Id == id })[0];
            let produtos = item.Produtos;
            if (item) {
                $('#lblTipo').text(item.Tipo);
                $('#lblNumeroGF').text(item.GfNumero);
                $('#lblNumeroDVPF').text(item.DvpfNumero);
                $('#lblRemetente').text(item.VendedorNome);
                $('#lblDestinatario').text(item.CompradorNome);
                $('#lblSituacao').text(item.SituacaoGfTexto);
                $('#lblClassificacao').text(item.Classificacao);
                $('#lblDataEmissao').text(item.EmissaoData);
                $('#lblConsumidorFinal').text(item.ConsumidorFinal);
                if (item.Exportacao == 0)
                    item.Exportacao = "";
                $('#lblExportacao').text(item.Exportacao);
                $('#lblEmbarque').text(item.Embarque);
                $('#lblCodigoBarras').text(item.CodigoDeBarra);
                $('#lblCpfCnpjVendedor').text(item.VendedorCpfCnpj);
                $('#lblCpfCnpjComprador').text(item.CompradorCpfCnpj);
                $('#lblMunicipioOrigem').text(item.VendedorMunicipio);
                $('#lblMunicipioDestino').text(item.MunicipioDestino);
                $('.tabelaProdutos tbody').html("");
                for (var i = 0; i < produtos.length; i++) {
                    $('.tabelaProdutos tbody').append("<tr><td><span>" + produtos[i].Essencia + "</span></td><td><span>" + produtos[i].Classificacao + "</span></td><td><span>" + produtos[i].Quantidade + "</span></td><td><span>" + produtos[i].Produto + "</span></td><td><span>" + produtos[i].UnidadeMedida + "</span></td></tr > ");
                }
                $('#modalDados').modal().show();

            } else {
                alert('Item não encontrado');
            }
        };

        $scope.consultar = function (form) {

            if (!form.tipo) {
                alert('Informe o tipo de GF');
                return;
            }
            if (!form.status) {
                alert('Informe o Status');
                return;
            }
            if (!form.codigoDeBarras) {
                if (!form.periodo) {
                    alert('Informe o Período');
                    return;
                }
            }

            $scope.isLoading = true;

            $http.post('views/transparencia/sistemas/service.aspx/SISFLORA_ConsultarDadosGF', {
                municipio: form.municipio || '',
                municipioDestino: form.municipioDestino || '',
                tipo: form.tipo || 0,
                status: form.status || 0,
                codigoDeBarras: form.codigoDeBarras || '',
                numeroGF: form.numeroGF || 0,
                periodo: form.periodo || 0,
                categoria: form.categoria || 0,
                essencia: form.essencia || ''
            }).then(function (success) {
                let data = JSON.parse(success.data.d);
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                $scope.dTableOptions.aaData = data.Lista.map(it => {
                    return {
                        tipo: it.Tipo,
                        numeroGF: it.GfNumero,
                        numeroDVPF: it.DvpfNumero,
                        remetente: it.VendedorNome + ' / ' + it.VendedorCpfCnpj,
                        destinatario: it.CompradorNome + ' / ' + it.CompradorCpfCnpj,
                        situacao: it.SituacaoGfTexto,
                        download: `<button class="btn btn-default " onclick="angular.element(this).scope().abrirModal('${it.Id}');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></div>`

                    };
                });

            }, function (error) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
            });
        };

        $scope.exportToJson = function () {
            sema.exportToJson($scope.dTableOptions.aaData, 'flores');
        };

        $scope.exportToCSV = function () {
            $(".buttons-csv").click();
        };
        $scope.exportToPDF = function () {
            $(".buttons-pdf").click();
        };
        $scope.exportToXLS = function () {
            $(".buttons-excel").click();
        };


    }]);
```

Comment: Bem, parece que na linha "$scope.dTableOptions.aaData = data.Lista.map(it => {", o atributo/Variavel 'Lista' não ta sendo declarado em nenhum lugar de seu código.
Veja se esta 'Lista' realmente existe, caso existe veja se possui valor, pois o erro está acusando que, o ".map" está tentando ser utilizado com algo indefinido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está na linha `$scope.dTableOptions.aaData = data.Lista.map(it => {`.

Provavelmente o atributo Lista, que é retornado da sua requisição, não não existe. O método `map` é uma propriedade de Arrays e só funcionará neles. Certifique-se de que a `Lista` exista e seja um Array.